# Cisco IOS NAT assistance

Tags: cisco

I am a cisco newbie, I have configured VLANS, dhcp, can get an IP address on my local machine.  I can't seem to get out to the internet from said machine.  Am I missing something in my NAT setup?

```
 Current configuration : 2220 bytes
    !
    ! Last configuration change at 00:46:14 UTC Wed Jan 27 2016
    !
    version 15.1
    service timestamps debug datetime msec
    service timestamps log datetime msec
    no service password-encryption
    !
    hostname Router
    !
    boot-start-marker
    boot-end-marker
    !
    !
    !
    no aaa new-model
    !
    !
    no ipv6 cef
    ip source-route
    ip cef
    !
    !
    !
    ip dhcp excluded-address 10.0.10.1
    !
    ip dhcp pool LAN1
    !
    ip dhcp pool LAN10
       network 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0
       default-router 10.0.10.1
       dns-server 8.8.8.8
    !
    ip dhcp pool vlan20
       network 10.0.20.0 255.255.255.0
       default-router 10.0.20.1
       dns-server 8.8.8.8
    !
    !
    !
    multilink bundle-name authenticated
    !
    crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
    !
    !
    license udi pid CISCO1921/K9 sn FTX151200G2
    !
    !
    !
    redundancy
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/0
     ip address dhcp
     ip nat outside
     ip virtual-reassembly in
     duplex auto
     speed auto
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1
     no ip address
     shutdown
     duplex auto
     speed auto
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0
     switchport access vlan 10
     spanning-tree portfast
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1/1
     switchport access vlan 10
     spanning-tree portfast
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1/2
     switchport access vlan 10
     spanning-tree portfast
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1/3
     switchport access vlan 10
     spanning-tree portfast
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1/4
     switchport access vlan 20
     spanning-tree portfast
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1/5
     switchport access vlan 20
     spanning-tree portfast
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1/6
     switchport access vlan 20
     spanning-tree portfast
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0/1/7
     switchport access vlan 20
     spanning-tree portfast
    !
    interface Vlan1
     no ip address
    !
    interface Vlan10
     ip address 10.0.10.1 255.255.255.0
     ip nat inside
     ip virtual-reassembly in
    !
    interface Vlan20
     ip address 10.0.20.1 255.255.255.0
     ip nat inside
     ip virtual-reassembly in
    !
    ip forward-protocol nd
    !
    no ip http server
    no ip http secure-server
    !
    ip nat source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
    !
    access-list 10 permit 10.0.10.0 0.0.0.255
    access-list 10 deny   any
    access-list 10 permit 10.0.20.0 0.0.0.255
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    !
    control-plane
    !
    !
    !
    line con 0
    line aux 0
    line vty 0 4
     login
     transport input all
    !
    scheduler allocate 20000 1000
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix, by making the following change:

```
ip nat source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
```

to

```
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
```

(`inside` was missing)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly cannot get out from VLAN20, because access-list 10 does not permit the IP-addresses in VLAN20, only those in VLAN10. The ACL entries are handled in order, so the deny any happens before the permit 10.0.20.0.

Comment: I will swap this.  I am on VLAN 10 with no access.

Comment: OK, then you need to debug this a bit more. You say you have a DHCP IP on your local machine, but do you get one on the router? What do you get if you `ping 8.8.8.8` from the router? If you try to access from your PC and then ask the Cisco `show ip nat translation`? If you do a `traceroute 8.8.8.8` from your PC?

Comment: Router#ping 8.8.8.8

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 8.8.8.8, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 20/23/24 ms
Router#

Comment: When I show ip nat translation
There is not response, blank line.

Comment: I was able to fix it.  Changed:
ip nat source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload


to
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload

Answer (score -1):

A little old, but maybe it will point you in the right direction.  http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/16448-default.html

Edit: Maybe the problem is related to setting a default route.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. Please provide content *here* and link elsewhere for more details if necessary.

Comment: Why recreate the wheel?

Comment: Because your answer becomes worthless when Cisco changes their URL structure, and 90% of the value of SE answers is not directly to the OP, but rather to the thousands of people that will land on this page during a google search in the future.

Comment: @Patches_McMatt not a bad idea about the default route, but dhcp should provide a default route